# How to restore symbol table on glibc 2.31 or newer version with .build-id folder?

Tags: c, symbols, glibc, ctf

There's no direct file like `libc-2.31-0ubuntu9.9.so` that with symbols, There's only `.build-id` folder inside the archive file.

[.build-id folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzpqB.png)

How can i restore the symbol table ? Searched on google or somewhere else. Found no one talked about this.

I download the libc file from the [glibc launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/2.31-0ubuntu9.9), tried either the `libc-bin-dbgsym 2.31-0ubuntu9` file or the `libc6-dbg_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb`. Both only have `.build-id` folder. And i don't know how to use them.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

> And i don't know how to use them.

You *install* the package, and then debuggers (such as GDB) will *know* how to use these `.build-id/...` files *automatically*.

That is, if you have an executable that crashed (e.g. `foo`) and a `core` file, invoke `gdb foo core` and GDB will automatically do the rest.

Or, without the `core` -- `gdb foo` then `(gdb) run`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i want to repack them into a binary file.
Manually put them into `.build-id` is a bit troublesome lol.

Is this the only way ?

Comment: @Kaguya http://xyproblem.info seems relevant here. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: sry for i forget this. I was doing problems on some CTF platforms. Currently doing some high version problem with Heap. That may use like version 2.27, 2.31, 2.34 or so on. Since 2.310ubuntu9.9. Theres no directly symbol table file in glibc launch pad.